# How to store values from Form in Database using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code for SubscriptionController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SubscribersController extends Controller
{
    //




//This method is to process the form
public function postSubmit() {

  //we check if it's really an AJAX request
  if(Request::ajax()) {

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
      //email field should be required, should be in an email//format, and should be unique
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers,email'
    )
    );

    if($validation->fails()) {
      return $validation->errors()->first();
    } else {

      $create = Subscribers::create(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email')
      ));

      if($create){
        return Redirect::to('/')
                       ->with('success','You have been successfully subscribe to us.');

      }else{
        echo 'We could not save your address to oursystem, please try again later';
      }

    }

  } else {
    return Redirect::to('subscribers');
  }
}
}
```

This is my code for Eloquent

```
class CreateSubscribersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('subscribers', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('email,100)->default('');
       $table->timestamps();
        });
    }.....
```

In the Route/web :

```
Route::post('/subscribers', 'SubscribersController');
```

This is the code for welcome.blade.php

```
  <form action="/subscribers" method="post">

      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

The code dont insert in database and dont show any error in the console. I put in the postsubmit function echos if error appears and nothing.
I already search one tutorial and dont find.
I´m a noob in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes should be `Route::post('/subscribers','SubscribersController@postSubmit');`
and add `csrf_field()` to form.

```
    <form action="/subscribers" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
   </form>`
```

Comment: @Norrris Oduro dont work... please review your answer.

Comment: @nodejscodrd change the button type to submit.

Comment: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'subscribers' not found
in SubscribersController.php (line 26)

Comment: `'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers,email',` in the validation rules to `'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers',`

Comment: its not that error is Class 'Subscribers' not found
in SubscribersController.php (line 27)

Comment: $create = Subscribers::create(array(
            'email' => $request->email,
        ));

change  `Subscribers::create` to `Subscriber::create` and import `App\Subscriber` in your Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153149/discussion-between-nodejscodrd-and-norris-oduro).

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file, your route need to send to an action, not just the controller.

`Route::post('/subscribers', 'SubscribersController');`

should be this

`Route::post('/subscribers', 'SubscribersController@postSubmit');`

And add the csrf field to your html form:

```
<form action="/subscribers" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Dont show any error, if you see my code in the controller this would show the errors, can you help me in this process? @Hollings?

Comment: Check the end of `laravel.log` file located in the `/storage/log/` folder for errors that your echos might not show

Comment: dont show anything, can you please check if the syntax is correct?

Comment: @nodejscodrd Please see my edit to my post about adding the `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: dont work... i have already see in the tab network if i receive any request. but nothing... dont send the form... is "stack"

Comment: after put input type submit i get this error Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: in SubscribersController.php (line 18)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153072/discussion-between-nodejscodrd-and-hollings).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you run :

```
php artisan migrate
```

Second, as Hollings stated above, your route :

```
Route::post('/subscribers', 'SubscribersController@postSubmit');
```

Third, top of your SubscribersController, add :

```
use Subscribers;
```

Aside of having CreateSubscribersTable extends Migration, you need to have another model class named Subscribers which extends Model. All class you might need to have :

```
SubscribersController extends Controller (you have it)

CreateSubscribersTable extends Migration (you have this too)

Subscribers extends Model/Eloquent (Do you have this?)
```

Sorry, that are all i can figure. Will try to check more to help.

Or if you really dying to figure out where the problem is, try to put echo something maybe "Test", within each of your if else.

Comment: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'subscribers' not found
in SubscribersController.php (line 26)

Comment: Class "Subscribers" not found is referring to the use of $create = Subscribers::create(array( 'email' => $request->email, )) . It state that the class does not exist. Are you sure you have that Subscribers model? Yes you have that CreateSubscribersTable, but that is your migration and not the actual model. You must have another class named Subscribers extends Model.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your `migration` content is wrong

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subscribers', function (Blueprint $table) { //** 'create', not 'table'
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email,100)->default('');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Delete your db contents and `php artisan migrate`

 
2) Your form is

```
<form action="/subscribers" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}  //** add token
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button> //** Button type : submit

</div>
</form>
```

Your route:

```
Route::post('/subscribers', 'SubscribersController@postSubmit');
```

Your controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Subscribers;        //********* change this

class SubscribersController extends Controller
{

    //This method is to process the form
    public function postSubmit(Request $request) {

        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            //email field should be required, should be in an email format, and should be unique

            'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers,email',
        ]);

        if($validation->fails()) {
            return $validation->errors()->first();
        }

        $create = Subscribers::create(array(
            'email' => $request->email,
        ));

        return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','You have been successfully subscribe to us.');

    }
}
```

Add `protected $table = 'subscribers';` to your `Subscribers` Model.

Why are you using `if (Request::ajax())` ? You are not submitting form via AJAX.

Comment: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'subscribers' not found
in SubscribersController.php (line 26)